# eclipse gives me an error "inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView" but i don't use it in project

Tags: android, eclipse

I run a project before few minutes regarding google maps and everything run fine.
I closed the project,emulator,restarted eclipse and when I try to run a previous project it gives me this error!The project has nothing to do with maps!
What can I do?

Comment: check inside any of your xml file is containing the MapView or not ? If possible post your activity code and the xml :)

Comment: it seems somehow I had inside xml the mapview!!i can't figure!maybe from the other project i was doing i copied sth!can you make it an answer in order to accepot?thanks!

Comment: can you post the log cat or dialog message .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check inside any of your `xml` file is containing the MapView or not. Especially the view that you are setting for the launching activity. Also make sure that in the run configuration you are not selecting the wrong project.